# Differential equation with the fundamental theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus

We have a first order linear differential equation $$y'=xy+2x$$
and a continuous function $f$ satisfies that $$f(x)=x^2+\int_{0}^{x}t f(t) dt$$, Show that $f$ is the unique solution to the first linear differential equation $$y'=xy+2x$$ with the initial condition $y(0)=0$

I tried to solve the differential equation and the solution is $$y=Ce^{x^2/2}-2$$, and with the initial condition, we get $C=2$,
and I was trying to differentiate $f(x)$ using Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, but I have no idea how to differentiate  $\int_{0}^{x}t f(t) dt$. Or is this the right way to solve this question? Anyone knows how to do this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\frac{d}{dx}\int_{0}^{x}g(t)dt$ = $\frac{d}{dx}(G(x)-G(0))$, where $G(x)$ is the antiderivative of $g(x)$. This is a direct consequence of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus. However, $\frac{d}{dx}(G(x)-G(0)) = g(x)$. Thus:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{0}^{x}tf(t)dt = xf(x)$$

Comment: yes, but then how to show that $f(x)$ is the unique solution to that differential equation?

Comment: how about the initial condition? and the unique solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you integrate both sides of the equation, you get

$$
\int_0^x y'(t) dt = \int_0^{x} t y(t) dt +\int_0^x 2t dt \Leftrightarrow y(x) = \underbrace{y(0)}_{=0}+\int_0^x t y(t) dt + x^2
$$

So, any solution of the equation is of the proposed form. On the other hand, this is a linear equation, for which you have existence and uniqueness of solution (and even a closed form solution).

Comment: Hi,$$
\int_0^x y'(t) dt = \int_0^{x} t y(t) dt +\int_0^x 2t dt \Leftrightarrow y(x) = \underbrace{y(0)}_{=0}+\int_0^x t y(t) dt + x^2
$$ Why y(0) is here?  Sorry, I am a slow learner.

Comment: @Logan When you integrate, you get
$$\int_0^x y'(t) dt = y(t)-y(0).$$